# CUDA compiler doesn't compile C files in same project

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, cuda, compiler-errors

I have `main.cu` file that includes `test.h` which is header for `test.c` and all three files are in same project.

*test.h code:*

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} struct_a;

void a(struct_a a);
```

*test.c code:*

```
void a(struct_a a) {
    printf("%d", a.a);
}
```

*main.cu code:*

```
struct_a b;
b.a=2;
a(b);
```

*Output when building the project:*

```
"nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2013 -ccbin "CUDA\v7.0\include" -I "CUDA\v7.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -o Debug\main.cu.obj "CudaTest\CudaTest\main.cu" 
1>  main.cu
1>  test.c
```

*Errors from building:*

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl a(struct struct_a)" (?a@@YAXUstruct_a@@@Z) referenced in function _main
```

If i include `test.c` instead of `test.h` in `main.cu` it works. 
I tried to separately compile `test.c`, i guess CUDA compiler doesn't include/compile/link(?) `test.c` file?

Comment: This looks like a C++ versus C linkage problem.

Comment: If i include test.c instead of test.h in main.cu it works.

Comment: rename test.c to test.cpp    Why does your output show `kernel.cu` ?

Comment: kernel.cu coz i replaced kernel with main for clarity, how ever when i changed it to .cpp it worked... can i by any chance have c source with .c extension?

Comment: Yes you can use .c files. But nvcc uses c++ style linkage so you'll have to handle the linkage correctly which is what @talonmies indicated. This question is a duplicate of many others like it already asked on the cuda tag. I'll find a duplicate and mark it as such eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As talonmies mentioned, CUDA uses C++ linkage. You need to add `extern "C"` qualifier to function declaration in `test.h`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void a(struct_a a);
```

See [In C++ source, what is the effect of extern "C"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c) for explanation.

Comment: I used extern "C" { #include test.h } in main.cu which also works

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but extern C makes templates impossible, however template works in the main.cu file. How to fix this issue?